# I cant remove/set children with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```js
function func(show = true) {
  var parent = $('#foo');
  var child = '<div id="bar"></div>';

  if (show)
    $(parent).fadeIn(350, function(){$(parent).html(child);});
  else
    $(parent).hide(0).delay(350, function() {
      $(parent.children()).remove()
    });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="foo"></div>
```

How can I do this better?, it doesn't work correctly and I don't know how to :(

Thanks!

Comment: Since your `bar` div has no value, no matter what you do you won't see anything work or not work.  Additionally, parent is a jQuery object so you don't need to wrap it again.  You can just `parent.fadeIn()`.  Why would you want to dynamically add and remove it?  Hiding it is much more performant then messing with the DOM.

Comment: Oh ok thanks!, i thought that this was gonna to boost my website, lmao... so ill add bar to foor in the html and just fadein and fadeout, thats right?

Comment: You want it to fade out too? You need to really describe in *words* what you want.  Showing code and just saying *it doesn't work* doesn't help us solve the problem because we don't know the problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: I have a loader, that shows everytime when ajax is done, so i show the loader with the function, and also hidding.... and i dont know if removing it and show it from the dom its better for my web perfomance or just keep the html in the body website you know, and fadein then .fadeout() or .hide(), i just want that my website load as fast possible.""simplifying"" stuff. hehe

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example. No need for jQuery to do presentation, CSS can do everything for you. There is no reason based on your question to do any DOM manipulation (removing adding div) so I didn't provide an example for it.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('input').on('click', function(){
    var isChecked = $(this).prop("checked");
    $('#foot').toggleClass("hidden", !isChecked);
    $('#bar').toggleClass("is-fading", isChecked);
  });
});
```

```css
.hidden {
  adisplay: none;
}
.fade-in{
opacity: 0;
}
.fade-in.is-fading{
transition: opacity 2.0s ease-in;
opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" value="test">Booya
<div id="foo" class="hiddne">
<div id="bar" class="fade-in">Hello</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

No idea about your use case, but I think, you are looking for some improvement in your code.

```js
function func(show = true) {
  var parent = $('#foo');
  var child = '<div class="bar">Hi Bar</div>';
  if (show)
    parent.fadeIn(350, function() {
      parent.html(child)
    });
  else
    parent.fadeOut(350);
}
```

Comment: No, it wont. You can try. Because I am simply setting up display none/block using jQuery methods.